# Error certificate and private keys

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a couple of days with certificate problems, I generate the. Ipa and certificates I have downloaded, but when I compile (Product-> Archive) gives me an error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' does not match any valid, non-expired certificate / private key pair in your keychains, there will be if you can help me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your certificate when you created the provisioning profile? If you did all the steps correctly you could delete your certificate from Keychain and try to recreate it.

Comment: Certified Copy of the previous developer app on my mac, and now I've tried to create a new profile but for some reason I did not Recognizes:
The identity 'iPhone Developer' does not match any valid, non-expired certificate / private key pair in your keychains

Comment: Ok, if I understood correctly you have downloaded the certificate from the previous developer? The certificate needs a private key and a public key, the key you download from the Apple provisioning portal is the public key. The private key is generated in the computer, which is the one I think you are missing. You could revoke the certificate and create a new one in your computer, that way the private key is generated.

Comment: I did it and it may be that not having developer certificate with the profile of my new mac is giving me problems?

Comment: After revoking the certificate and creating a new one, you need to recreate the provisioning profile and download it again. Before installing the new profile, I suggest to delete the provisioning profile (the one that doesn't work), from the Organizer in xCode so you have a better overview.

Comment: thanks , solucionate!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the bundle identifier in your build settings matches that of the provision profile, the profile which was signed with the certificate that you have in your keychain.

Comment: I have two profiles in my library, I may have to create one for my mac since it is the first time you compile on my mac, can it be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the bundle identifier name is as same as Provisioning profile name. check that if not matches then create new provisioning profile and set bundle identifier same.

Comment: I've created a new profile and I say this in the organizer: valid signing identity not found